# Connecting MTi-G-710 sensor to PC using RS422 to USB adapter

Tags: sensors, connector

I tried to connect an [MTi-G-710](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/movella-technologies-b-v/MTI-G-710-2A8G4/10667484) sensor to PC using [this RS422 to USB adapter](https://www.aten.com/global/en/products/usb-solutions/converters/uc485/). I connected the wires from the sensor directly to the terminal block, using [this wire color guide](https://base.xsens.com/s/article/MTi-10-100-series-connectors-and-cables?language=en_US).
When I connected it to the PC, it wouldn't recognize my sensor. I also tried:

- supplying Vin separately (using both USB power, a 9V battery and a 12V charger)
- switching the echo / no echo and no term / term switches on the adapter
- checking the continuity of the wires from the terminal to the other end of the cable, one by one

Here are some photos of the connections that I've made:

The sensor wires, connected in the terminal block

[image: The sensor wires, connected in the terminal block]

The adapter, switched to the 422 mode, with echo disabled and terminal resistance enabled

[image: The adapter, switched to the 422 mode, with echo disabled and terminal resistance enabled]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried a direct USB connection?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I'm not quite sure what are you suggesting exactly

Comment: the link you posted for the sensor, lists USB as one of the connection options

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using this cable, per the table and your photo, the Rx pair from the sensor is being connected to your USB-RS422 connector's Rx and same for Tx pair. For serial communications, the transmit on one device needs to be connected to receive on the other; if you flip the Rx and Tx connections on your USB-RS422 convertor, you should be able to communicate with the sensor.

[image: Cable],

Edit: Here's an article that popped up on Googling - describes various types of serial links, and also shows how to connect two RS422 devices.
https://ipc2u.com/articles/knowledge-base/the-main-differences-between-rs-232-rs-422-and-rs-485/